# Como hago para enviar un string con getText desde un spinner?

Tags: java, android

**Hola** a todos, tengo un problema para enviar getText desde un spinner, necesito que la opcion seleccionada del spinner vaya a otra actividad de java.

esta es la **linea 1** del spinner que debe enviar la informacion, y se encuentra en java activity_main

```
editor.putString("RUTA", spnrEmployee.getText().toString().trim());
```

y esta es la **linea 2** que recibe la información de la anterior, y se encuentra en otra actividad (activity2) de java

```
requestParams.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("RUTA", ""));
```

A continuación adjunto el activitymain

```
package com.websmithing.gpstracker;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

import java.util.UUID;

import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GpsTrackerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EmployeeNamearray = "EmpName";
    public static final String EmployeeName  = "EmpName";
    public static final String EmployeeMailid = "EmpMailid";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    private JSONArray result;
    Spinner spinner;
    String EmpName;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    TextView employeename,mailid;

    private static final String TAG = "GpsTrackerActivity";

    // use the websmithing defaultUploadWebsite for testing and then check your
    // location with your browser here: https://www.websmithing.com/gpstracker/displaymap.php
    private String defaultUploadWebsite;

    //private EditText txtUserName;
    private Spinner spnrEmployee;
    private EditText txtWebsite;
    private Button trackingButton;

    private boolean currentlyTracking;
    private RadioGroup intervalRadioGroup;
    private int intervalInMinutes = 1;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Intent gpsTrackerIntent;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps_tracker);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        defaultUploadWebsite = getString(R.string.default_upload_website);



        txtWebsite = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtWebsite);
       // txtUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        spnrEmployee = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnrEmployee);
        intervalRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.intervalRadioGroup);
        trackingButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trackingButton);
        //txtUserName.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentlyTracking = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("currentlyTracking", false);

        boolean firstTimeLoadingApp = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTimeLoadingApp", true);
        if (firstTimeLoadingApp) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstTimeLoadingApp", false);
            editor.putString("appID",  UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            editor.apply();
        }


        intervalRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                        saveInterval();
                    }
                });

        trackingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                trackLocation(view);
            }
        });


        //SAAG
        spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrEmployee);
        employeename= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        mailid= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvmailid);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        getdata();
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
                employeename.setText("Name: "+getemployeeName(position));
                mailid.setText("Mail Id: "+getmailid(position));

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                employeename.setText("");
                mailid.setText("");
            }
        });


    }

    private void getdata() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("http://190.147.68.37/ejemplos/datos.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            j = new JSONObject(response);
                            result = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
                            empdetails(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    private void empdetails(JSONArray j) {

        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(json.getString(EmployeeNamearray));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // arrayList.add(0,"Select Employee");

        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(GpsTrackerActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList));

    }
    //Method to get student name of a particular position
    private String getemployeeName(int position){
        String name="";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);

            //Fetching name from that object
            name = json.getString( EmployeeName);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return name;
    }

    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()
    private String getmailid(int position){
        String mailid="";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            mailid = json.getString( EmployeeMailid);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mailid;
    }


    private void saveInterval() {
        if (currentlyTracking) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.user_needs_to_restart_tracking, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        switch (intervalRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.i1:
                editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 1);
                break;
            case R.id.i5:
                editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 5);
                break;
            case R.id.i15:
                editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 15);
                break;
        }

        editor.apply();
    }


    private void startAlarmManager() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startAlarmManager");

        Context context = getBaseContext();
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        gpsTrackerIntent = new Intent(context, GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, gpsTrackerIntent, 0);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        intervalInMinutes = sharedPreferences.getInt("intervalInMinutes", 1);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                intervalInMinutes * 60000, // 60000 = 1 minute
                pendingIntent);
    }

    private void cancelAlarmManager() {
        Log.d(TAG, "cancelAlarmManager");

        Context context = getBaseContext();
        Intent gpsTrackerIntent = new Intent(context, GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, gpsTrackerIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }

    // called when trackingButton is tapped
    protected void trackLocation(View v) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        if (!saveUserSettings()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!checkIfGooglePlayEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        if (currentlyTracking) {
            cancelAlarmManager();

            currentlyTracking = false;
            editor.putBoolean("currentlyTracking", false);
            editor.putString("sessionID", "");
        } else {
            startAlarmManager();

            currentlyTracking = true;
            editor.putBoolean("currentlyTracking", true);
            editor.putFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", 0f);
            editor.putBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", true);
            editor.putString("sessionID",  UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }

        editor.apply();
        setTrackingButtonState();
    }

    private boolean saveUserSettings() {
        if (textFieldsAreEmptyOrHaveSpaces()) {
            return false;
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        switch (intervalRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.i1:
                editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 1);
                break;
            case R.id.i5:
                editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 5);
                break;
            case R.id.i15:
                editor.putInt("intervalInMinutes", 15);
                break;
        }

// esta es la linea 1 del spinner spnrEmployee
        editor.putString("RUTA", spnrEmployee.getText().toString().trim());
        editor.putString("defaultUploadWebsite", txtWebsite.getText().toString().trim());
        editor.apply();

        return true;
    }

    private boolean textFieldsAreEmptyOrHaveSpaces() {
      //  String tempUserName = txtUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String tempWebsite = txtWebsite.getText().toString().trim();

        if (tempWebsite.length() == 0 || hasSpaces(tempWebsite) /*|| tempUserName.length() == 0 || hasSpaces(tempUserName)*/) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.textfields_empty_or_spaces, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean hasSpaces(String str) {
        return ((str.split(" ").length > 1) ? true : false);
    }

    private void displayUserSettings() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        intervalInMinutes = sharedPreferences.getInt("intervalInMinutes", 1);

        switch (intervalInMinutes) {
            case 1:
                intervalRadioGroup.check(R.id.i1);
                break;
            case 5:
                intervalRadioGroup.check(R.id.i5);
                break;
            case 15:
                intervalRadioGroup.check(R.id.i15);
                break;
        }

        txtWebsite.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("defaultUploadWebsite", defaultUploadWebsite));

        //spnrEmployee.setSelection(sharedPreferences.getInt("ruta",0));

    }

    private boolean checkIfGooglePlayEnabled() {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.google_play_services_unavailable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void setTrackingButtonState() {
        if (currentlyTracking) {
            trackingButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_tracking_button);
            trackingButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            trackingButton.setText(R.string.tracking_is_on);
        } else {
            trackingButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_tracking_button);
            trackingButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            trackingButton.setText(R.string.tracking_is_off);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

        displayUserSettings();
        setTrackingButtonState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

a continuación adjunto la **actividad2** que procesa los datos para llevarlos a la base de datos

```
package com.websmithing.gpstracker;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

//import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

public class LocationService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";

    // use the websmithing defaultUploadWebsite for testing and then check your
    // location with your browser here: https://www.websmithing.com/gpstracker/displaymap.php
    private String defaultUploadWebsite;

    private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        defaultUploadWebsite = getString(R.string.default_upload_website);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // if we are currently trying to get a location and the alarm manager has called this again,
        // no need to start processing a new location.
        if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
            currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
            startTracking();
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startTracking() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startTracking");

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
        }
    }

    protected void sendLocationDataToWebsite(Location location) {
        // formatted for mysql datetime format
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date(location.getTime());

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        float totalDistanceInMeters = sharedPreferences.getFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", 0f);

        boolean firstTimeGettingPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", true);

        if (firstTimeGettingPosition) {
            editor.putBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", false);
        } else {
            Location previousLocation = new Location("");
            previousLocation.setLatitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLatitude", 0f));
            previousLocation.setLongitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLongitude", 0f));

            float distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
            totalDistanceInMeters += distance;
            editor.putFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", totalDistanceInMeters);
        }

        editor.putFloat("previousLatitude", (float)location.getLatitude());
        editor.putFloat("previousLongitude", (float)location.getLongitude());
        editor.apply();

        final RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
        requestParams.put("latitude", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
        requestParams.put("longitude", Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));

        Double speedInMilesPerHour = location.getSpeed()* 2.2369;
        requestParams.put("speed",  Integer.toString(speedInMilesPerHour.intValue()));

        try {
            requestParams.put("date", URLEncoder.encode(dateFormat.format(date), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}

        requestParams.put("locationmethod", location.getProvider());

        if (totalDistanceInMeters > 0) {
            requestParams.put("distance", String.format("%.1f", totalDistanceInMeters / 1609)); // in miles,
        } else {
            requestParams.put("distance", "0.0"); // in miles
        }

        //requestParams.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("userName", ""));
       // spnrEmployee.setSelection(sharedPreferences.getInt("position",0));

        requestParams.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("RUTA", ""));
        requestParams.put("phonenumber", sharedPreferences.getString("appID", "")); // uuid
        requestParams.put("sessionid", sharedPreferences.getString("sessionID", "")); // uuid

        Double accuracyInFeet = location.getAccuracy()* 3.28;
        requestParams.put("accuracy",  Integer.toString(accuracyInFeet.intValue()));

        Double altitudeInFeet = location.getAltitude() * 3.28;
        requestParams.put("extrainfo",  Integer.toString(altitudeInFeet.intValue()));

        requestParams.put("eventtype", "android");

        Float direction = location.getBearing();
        requestParams.put("direction",  Integer.toString(direction.intValue()));

        final String uploadWebsite = sharedPreferences.getString("defaultUploadWebsite", defaultUploadWebsite);

        LoopjHttpClient.get(uploadWebsite, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                LoopjHttpClient.debugLoopJ(TAG, "sendLocationDataToWebsite - success", uploadWebsite, requestParams, responseBody, headers, statusCode, null);
                stopSelf();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                LoopjHttpClient.debugLoopJ(TAG, "sendLocationDataToWebsite - failure", uploadWebsite, requestParams, errorResponse, headers, statusCode, e);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "position: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude() + " accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());

            // we have our desired accuracy of 500 meters so lets quit this service,
            // onDestroy will be called and stop our location uodates
            if (location.getAccuracy() < 500.0f) {
                stopLocationUpdates();
                sendLocationDataToWebsite(location);
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000); // milliseconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // the fastest rate in milliseconds at which your app can handle location updates
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");

        stopLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagino quieres leer los valores de RUTA, defaultUploadWebsite y intervalInMinutes en otra Activity, si estas salvando estos valores en una Preferencia puedes obtenerlos en otro punto de tu aplicación.

Comment: lo que sucede es lo siguiente, el spinner tiene el id spnrEmployee, necesito, que el valor seleccionado de este, lo lea la otra actividad que creo que es la que recibe el valor del spinner con esta linea
requestParams.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("RUTA", ""));
Disculpa de java poco, es algo que estoy tratando de hacer, gracias

Comment: Con "id" te refieres a :   android:id="@+id/spnrEmployee" ? @AndresArango

Comment: si correcto, necesitas que adjunte todo el activitymain?, mil gracias

Comment: He agregado una actualización @AndresArango , en cuanto a txtWebsite puedes obtener la referencia de la misma forma.

Answer (score -1):

Si estas realizando el guardado de valores en una Preferencia, no necesitas enviarlos, puedes abrir la preferencia y buscar los valores que previamente guardaste:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String valorRuta = sharedPreferences.getString("RUTA", "");
String valordefaultUploadWebsite = sharedPreferences.getString("defaultUploadWebsite", "");
int valorIntervalInMinutes = sharedPreferences.getInt("intervalInMinutes", 0);
```

---

Para obtener la referencia del `Spinner` se realiza de esta forma, primeramente declaras una variable tipo `Spinner`:

```
private Spinner spnrEmployee;
```

y dentro de onCreate() puedes obtener la referencia:

```
 spnrEmployee = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrEmployee);
```

Comment: Hola, acabo de actualizar las actividades de java completas, la main es donde el spinner spnrEmployee, debería enviarle la selección RUTA a la segunda actividad, para guardarlo a la base de datos.